# How to show custom logs from App to Crashlytics dashboard

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

I am trying to report custom logs from my app to Crashlytics without any crashes. I want to log a particular button action and display it in the Crashlytics dashboard. Is there a way to do this in Crashlytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)recordError:(NSError *)error;
- (void)recordError:(NSError *)error withAdditionalUserInfo:(nullable CLS_GENERIC_NSDICTIONARY(NSString *, id) *)userInfo;
```

Just use the instance of Crashlytics and you can receive your non-fatal issue with the custom error.

Also, you can send additional logs

```
CLSLog(NSString *format, ...)
```

And will be helpful to use Answers if you need to see some actions statistic or events.

```
+ (void)logCustomEventWithName:(NSString *)eventName
          customAttributes:(nullable ANS_GENERIC_NSDICTIONARY(NSString *, id) *)customAttributesOrNil;
```

Comment: CLSLogv("Log awesomeness %d %d %@", getVaList([1, 2, "two"])) I used this function in swift button click but not seeing anything in dashboard..

Comment: At first, you need to send the non-fatal issue. The logs will available in issue details 'View all sessions' button. So just add some   CLSLogv after perform recordError

Comment: thanks paul for the answer but i am completely new with this, can you walk me through here how to use this in button click ..?

Comment: https://fabric.io/kits/ios/answers/features
https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/features
I believe you can find excellent examples in fabric docs